# Set-ADAccountPassword to change password + Set-ADUser to change password at next logon

Tags: windows, powershell

I started to learn powershell in order to provide various tools for my colleagues at work (HelpDesk). I managed to get the following for the reset password:

```
Set-ADUser -Credential $Desk -Identity $User -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Confirm |
    Set-ADAccountPassword $User -Credential $Desk -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Reset -Force -Verbose) -PassThru
```

The problem is that the script will only record one of those inputs:

1. If I start with `Set-ADUser`, the password will have to change at next logon but will not change to the value I entered.
2. If I start with `Set-ADAccountPassword`, it will change the password but not prompt the user to switch at next logon.

I know my code is pretty basic but it's under development and I will restructure it later on when I know that the basic function are working.

To give you a background about the rest of the script:
A list of various commands shows up (Unlock user, Ping, NSlookup, Remote Connection and others) and you chose which option you want. After that, the script will jump to the tool linked to it and perform while prompting the user if needed. The variables present in this code are all generated through prompt window.

EDIT: I found a way around it by simply prompting the user of my script to confirm after resetting the password if they want to enable "Change password at next logon". The added code looks like this:
`$ChangePWD = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to enable "Change password at next logon? Y/N'if ($ChangePWD -eq "Y"){Set-ADUser -Credential $Desk -Identity $userObject -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -confirm    }`

Thank you though for all the basic information I should have known.

Comment: It looks like you dont really know what a pipeline does. `Set-ADuser` doesn't supply an Object that can be parsed to `Set-ADAccountPassword`. Seperate both commands either by a new line or with `;`.

Take a look at (https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-pipeline.html)

Comment: `Set-Aduser` supports  `-PassThru` so you should be able to add that before you pipe. You _could_ also switch the commands around as it is not clear why you are using `-PassThru` on the end there.

Comment: @Paxz As stated, I never learned powershell until today, therefore I do agree with you, I don't completely know how to use pipe (But I'll make sure to look into that). Thanks for the link

Comment: @Matt I did it the other way around before posting my case here, it was the same so I wondered if the order of my requests could impact what I'm doing and that's why I 've put the '-PassThru' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should run these commands in a different order.  When you run `Set-ADUserAccountPassword` that *unchecks* the 'User must change password at next login' box.

```
$userObject = Get-ADUser -Identity $User
Set-ADAccountPassword $userObject -Credential $Desk -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Reset -Force -Verbose)
Set-ADUser -Credential $Desk -Identity $userObject -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -confirm
```

Comment: Hi FoxDeploy, I tried to include that in my script but I have the same issue, it does change the password but it won't check the box in AD "Change password at next logon". The script ran without error message. I wonder if it's even possible to include both action. When I run the Set-ADUser and the Set-ADAccountPassword separately, it works. It won't work when I try to run them both at the same time.

Comment: I totally changed my answer.  I think it was command order that caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick and changed bot entries in AD:

```
EDIT: I found a way around it by simply prompting the user of my script to confirm after resetting the password if they want to enable "Change password at next logon". The added code looks like this:
```

$ChangePWD = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you want to enable "Change password at next logon? Y/N'if ($ChangePWD -eq "Y"){Set-ADUser -Credential $Desk -Identity $userObject -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -confirm    }